# Docker-compose unable to connect static ip

Tags: python, docker, tor, stem

For some needs I'd like a python app to connect to a tor proxy but instead of the DNS I want to use the static ip. Indeed when I

I'm unable to make it happen. The request is always timed out when I want to connect to the database.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    command: ifconfig
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.18.9

  app:
    build: ./python
    depends_on:
      - tor

  tor:
    build:
      context: ./tor
    container_name: tor
    environment:
      - TOR_INSTANCES=1
      - TOR_HASHED_PASSWORD=16:D87F66F5B5E2A6BC605544DBB4720DAD433C1E8CE7D18F835D58A4353E
      - TOR_PROXIES_CONTROLLER_AUTH_PASSWORD=testtor
      - TOR_CONTROLLER_HOST=172.18.18.10
    ports:
      - "9050-9060:9050-9060"
      - "10000-10050:10000-10050"
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.18.10

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.18.0/24
          gateway: 172.18.18.1
```

My python code is very simple, this is what i'm trying to do :

- Get IP from requests (without proxies)
- Same but with proxy
- Renew proxy
- Perform requests again

The first request passes well but then it timeouts with the proxies. Obvisously I can't renew the IP either as the ip so not resolved.

```
^[[Dapp_1   | After request ::  https://ifconfig.io/ip 200 82.123.30.131
app_1   | 
app_1   | SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='ifconfig.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0xffffbcb16940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
app_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stem/socket.py", line 535, in _make_socket
app_1   |     control_socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
app_1   | TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

However if I only execute the tor docker-container, and I replace the tor proxy by "localhost", it works totally fine :

```
    def add_proxies(self):
        self.http.proxies['http'] = 'socks5://localhost:9051'
        self.http.proxies['https'] = 'socks5://localhost:9051'

    def renew_proxy_ip(self):
        with Controller.from_port(port=10001) as controller:
            controller.authenticate(password="testtor")
            print("Authentication :: ", controller.is_authenticated())
            controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Output is expected

```
After request ::  https://ifconfig.io/ip 200 2a01:cb04:be0:b300:d44d:f8d3:6328:b2f1

After request ::  https://ifconfig.io/ip 200 2a00:1768:6001:28:2236::1

Authentication ::  True
After request ::  https://ifconfig.io/ip 200 2a03:4000:37:645::
```

I added a ifconfig busybox to see if ip is correctly mapped, which is the case :

```
test_1  | eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:12:12:09  
test_1  |           inet addr:172.18.18.9  Bcast:172.18.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
test_1  |           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
test_1  |           RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
test_1  |           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
test_1  |           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
test_1  |           RX bytes:200 (200.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
test_1  | 
test_1  | lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
test_1  |           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
test_1  |           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
test_1  |           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
test_1  |           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
test_1  |           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
test_1  |           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I created a repo where you can reproduce the issue : https://github.com/thibault-lr/docker-static-ip simply with a `docker-compose up`

I'm a bit obliged to proceed so, the controller authication requires an IP to connect to. I've been stuck to this for a while, I'd like to know if someone experienced this issue already ? I'm on macos and tried on a linux server it remains the same

There are other solutions that I didn't explore if this is not possible :

- Use the telnet to connect to tor network using a DNS
- Auth with socket files

Huge thanks in advance !
TL

Comment: try adding  networks: - app_net to app container as well. so all the containers are on same n/w

Comment: O.M.G, thank you so much this is it ! Works like a charm. How come by the way ? App container was considered as external and could not connect ?

Comment: Since you have added app_net for other two containers, they will be available in that network, whereas the app container will be in bridge n/w by default. So either you bring them all under one n/w or remove the n/w from all